# Does the range of a linearly growing sequence have positive density in the integers?

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf, integer-sequences

Let $f(n)$ be a sequence of positive integers such that the limit $\alpha=\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)/n$ exists and is a finite number greater than 1. Is it true that the range $R$  of this sequence has positive density in the integers in the sense that
$\lim \inf_N|R\cap \{1,...,N\}|/N>0$?

Can this lim inf be bounded below in terms of $\alpha$? Is it equal to $1/\alpha$? Any intuition appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean to assume that $f(n)$ is injective (no repeated values)? Then yes, the density will be $1/\alpha$. Just use $|f(n)/n-\alpha|<\varepsilon$ when $n$ is large; if $y_0$ is the largest element of $R$ less than $N$, those inequalities will give you upper and lower bounds for the $n_0$ such that $f(n_0)=y_0$.

Comment: @GregMartin no I definitely do not want to assume the sequence is injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without assuming that $f$ is injective, the answer is certainly no. For a counterexample, define $f(n) = \lfloor \sqrt{2n} \rfloor^2$. Then the range of $f$ is contained in the set of perfect squares and thus has density $0$. On the other hand,
$f(n) = (\sqrt{2n}+O(1))^2 = 2n + O(\sqrt n)$
and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/n = 2$.

(In this counterexample one can change the $2$ to any positive number $\alpha$, including $\alpha\in(0,1]$. There are lots of other variants as well, such as letting $f(n)$ be the smallest prime exceeding $2n$.)